# laravel query building for inner join

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to built query for the below mysql query ?

`SELECT routes.id, src.title, dest.title, groups.title FROM routes INNER JOIN locations as src ON (src.id = routes.src) INNER JOIN locations as dest ON (dest.id = routes.dest) INNER JOIN groups ON (groups.id = routes.groups) order by routes.id`

Comment: Have you tried any way?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the difference between src.title and dest.title but this query will help you.

```
 DB::table('routes')->select('routes.id','src.title', 'groups.title')->join('locations as src', 'routes.src', '=', 'src.id')->join('groups', 'routes.groups', '=', 'groups.id')->orderBy('routes.id','DESC')->get();
```